# Changing the colour of a SKShapeNode when touched?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I have a game where i touch a node and it runs some code. How do I change the SKShapeNode's color when touched? I tried to use node.fillColor = SKColor.blackcolor() for example but it says that I cannot do that even though thats how i originally created the SKShapeNode's color in the first place.

This is all writing within touches began method.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) { 
    for touch: AnyObject in touches { 
        let positionOfTouch = touch.locationInNode(self) 
        let node = nodeAtPoint(positionOfTouch)         
        node.userInteractionEnabled = true 
        node.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

This is the code I am using. But it keeps saying "Value of type SKNode has no member "fillColor"...But "fillColor" works in my DidMoveToView.
Thanks

Comment: Show us the code. Are you sure you are picking up the correct node?

Comment: override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let positionOfTouch = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let node = nodeAtPoint(positionOfTouch)
            node.userInteractionEnabled = true
            node.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

This is the code I am using. But it keeps saying "Value of type SKNode has no member "fillColor"...But "fillColor" works in my DidMoveToView..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node you are likely to touch may be a parent or child node - an `SKNode`, not an `SKShapeNode`. That's what `nodeAtPoint` returns, and a generic `SKNode` doesn't have a `fillColor`. You need to check it is the class you are expecting by testing. Something like...

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) { 
    for touch: AnyObject in touches { 
        let positionOfTouch = touch.locationInNode(self) 
        if let node = nodeAtPoint(positionOfTouch) as? SKShapeNode {
            node.userInteractionEnabled = true 
            node.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: Thank you Grimxn! Cannot believe it was that simple to fix. Cheers for your help.